# a continuous function on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Is there a continuous bijective function from $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I think that there is no such function. The set $|[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}|$ is countable and $|\mathbb{R}|$ is uncountable. Hence every continuous function from $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is not bijective.

Is it true?

Comment: Yes, there are no bijections between sets of unequal cardinality.

Comment: As you say, there can be no surjection from a countable set onto an uncountable one.  "continuous" is not needed and not really defined until you say what topology you want on the left.  If the discrete topology, then all functions are continuous.

Comment: Yes. In particular, no function $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$ can be surjective.

Comment: But you can get the next best thing: A continuous injective function on $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ whose image is dense in $\mathbb R$. This is not possible with domain $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your argument is correct.

Except for a slight notational nitpick: You ought to say that e.g. $A$ is countable, not that $|A|$ is countable. The notation $|A|$ means the *cardinality* of $A$, but it is the set itself that is "countable".